# Accessing class constant from abstract method in PHP5

Tags: php, constants, abstract-class

I'm trying to get the value of a constant of an extending class, but in a method of the abstract class. Like this:

```
    abstract class Foo {
        public function method() {
            echo self::constant;
        }
    }

    class Bar extends Foo {
        const constant = "I am a constant";
    }

    $bar = new Bar();
    $bar->method();
```

This however results in a fatal error. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. A possible solution would be to create a virtual method that returns the desired value in the subclasses, i.e.

```
abstract class Foo {
  protected abstract function getBar();

  public function method() {
    return $this->getBar();
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  protected function getBar() {
    return "bar";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### This is possible using the Late Static Binding keyword introduced in PHP 5.3

Essentially, `self` refers to the current class that the code is written in, but `static` refers to the class the code is running from.

We could rewrite your code snippet as:

```php
abstract class Foo {
    public function method() {
        echo static::constant;    // Note the static keyword here
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    const constant = "I am a constant";
}

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->method();
```

However, this pattern of coding is dirty and you should probably instead introduce a protected api between your parent class and subclasses to funnel that kind of information back and forth.

So from a code organization perspective, I would lean more towards the solution that **Morfildur** put forward.